# CLAMAV Issue after i removed it

Tags: clamav, cron.daily

Here is my issue:
I removed clamav, spamassasin, and amavis and now I am getting this in my Citadel email box every day from some cron job that is searching for Clamav.

How do I amend the Cron job to stop checking for Clamav? Where is the cron job taks located? I looked at /etc/cron and /etc/cron.d as well as various other files such as anacron, crond, etc. I cannot seem to find out where I can amend the job to take this job out of the loop.

Here is the Error I get each day:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: clamav-daemon:6 unknown user 'clamav'
error: found error in /var/log/clamav/clamav.log , skipping
error: clamav-freshclam:7 unknown user 'clamav'
error: found error in /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log , skipping
error: clamav-milter:6 unknown user 'clamav'
error: found error in /var/log/clamav/clamav-milter.log , skipping
error: stat of /var/log/clamav/clamav.log failed: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is telling you the cron job: `/etc/cron.d/logrotate`.  Look in `/etc/logrotate.conf` or under directory `/etc/logrotate.d` for the referenced entries; from the format of the error messages, I would guess at there being

- `/etc/logrotate.d/clamav-daemon`
- `/etc/logrotate.d/clamav-freshclam`
- `/etc/logrotate.d/clamav-milter`

which would need to be removed.

Comment: Yes there was those files within the /etc/logrotate.d/ directory.  I have removed those 3 files.  I will look at the log again tomorrow and I am sure they will no longer be there thanks to you.